# Deploying a .jar into a html page

Tags: java, html, deployment, jar, applet

So I have the following code in Java which deploys an applet into a `html` page.

Due to security problems I'm trying to make it a .jar and then sign that `.jar` to see first how that will work.

Unfortunately I'm not really sure what I should change in order to run it as a `.jar`, given that the main class in the `.jar` is the same:

```
p.println(document+"<applet name=\"myApp\" codebase="+codebase+" code="+code+ " width='+(scnWid-30)+' height='+(scnHei-45)+'>');");
        p.println(document+"<param name=user value=\""+user+"\">');");
        p.println(document+"<param name=sessionid value=\""+sessionid+"\">');");
```

Where codebase and code are taken here :

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            super.init(config);
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            applet_code_base = context.getInitParameter("applet_code_base");
            applet_code = context.getInitParameter("applet_code");

          }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your question is? Or maybe more detail about the 'security problems' you're having?

Comment: Well, i want to know what should i add to my code in order to run a .jar inside the html page (a .jar that is basically that applet). I tried adding archive="myjar.jar" but it didnt worked (even though myjar.jar was in the same directory as the main class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle website at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) location says:

> To start any applet from an HTML file for running inside a browser,
>   you use the applet tag. For more information, see the Java Applets
>   lesson. If the applet is bundled as a JAR file, the only thing you
>   need to do differently is to use the archive parameter to specify the
>   relative path to the JAR file.

It claims that

```
<applet code=TicTacToe.class 
        archive="TicTacToe.jar"
        width="120" height="120">
</applet>
```

is the appropriate `html` code to display an applet stored as `TicTacToe.jar` in the same directory as the `html` file.

Answer (score 2):

Reference [Deploying An Applet In Under 10 Minutes](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deploying_an_applet_in_under) :

1. Compile / build your applet's Java code and make sure all class
   files and resources such as images etc. are in a separate directory,
   example `build/components`.
2. Create a `jar` file containing your applet's
   class files and resources.

   `cd build`

   `jar cvf  DynamicTreeDemo.jar components`
3. Sign your `jar` file if the applet needs
   special security permissions, for example, to be launched in a modern JRE with default settings. By default, unsigned code will be blocked.

   `jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore -storepass abc123 -keypass abc123 DynamicTreeDemo.jar johndoe`

   where keystore is setup and located at "myKeyStore"
   alias is "johndoe"
   keystore password and alias password are "abc123"
4. Create a `JNLP` file that describes how your applet
   should be launched.

dynamictree-applet.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Dynamic Tree Demo</title>
        <vendor>Dynamic Team</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
              max-heap-size="128m" />

        <jar href="DynamicTreeDemo.jar" main="true" />

    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="Dynamic Tree Demo Applet"
         main-class="components.DynamicTreeApplet"
         width="300"
         height="300">
     </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

5. Create the HTML page that will display the applet. Invoke the runApplet function from the Deployment Toolkit to deploy the applet.

AppletPage.html

```
<body>
    ....
    <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

    <script> 
        var attributes = { code:'components.DynamicTreeApplet',  width:300, height:300} ; 
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'dynamictree-applet.jnlp'} ; 
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
    </script>
    ....
</body>
```

6. For this example, place `DynamicTreeDemo.jar`, `dynamictree-applet.jnlp`, and `AppletPage.html` in the same directory on the local machine or a web server. A web server is not required for testing this applet.
7. View `AppletPage.html in a web browser. The Dynamic Tree Demo Applet will be displayed. View Java Console Log for error and debug messages.

For more information see [Deployment Toolkit 101 - Java Tutorials Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deployment_toolkit_101)

Comment: Ok, I kinda understood this, but the problem I encounter is that my html page is build using java so I can't put the Applet.html into the same directory as the others because it really doesn't exist.

Comment: Nowadays the applet tag is unsupported. Is there anyway I can run a jar file without applet?