# How can I execute jar file from HTML?

Tags: html, jar

I have a `.jar` file which I want to be execute by a button on a HTML page.
Is it even possible? I couldn't find any info about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373757/deploying-a-jar-into-a-html-page

Comment: I don't know if it's my fault, but every time when I try to do it with applet it's not working...